# Interpretation of this Java Fatal Error (EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION)

Tags: java, swing, native

Hello I now tried to fix this Error since 1 day but can't figure it out, the Error ist reproductable, but with different ways to cause it (!!), sometimes even without doing an active action in the GUI.

The Code should stream from a camera, and I'm using the native library of the camera, I use netbeans.

I tried reinstall JDK, Netbeans and also running the code in Eclipse..

I maybe think it's something with the jvm.dll but i didn't know how to fix that..

I found this solution [JVM Fatal Error in native code, Not sure what to do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7636614/jvm-fatal-error-in-native-code-not-sure-what-to-do), but to set the System Property to false only worked for 5-15 seconds...

Here is the Erro Code from the console and than from the log file

```
## A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x6e9954bb, pid=1796, tid=3208
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_79-b15) (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (24.79-b02 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0xc54bb]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#



---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x0311a000):  JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-0" [_thread_in_vm, id=3208, stack(0x032a0000,0x032f0000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x00000000

Registers:
EAX=0x00000000, EBX=0x32d029f0, ECX=0x0311a000, EDX=0x0000101b
ESP=0x032ef160, EBP=0x032ef17c, ESI=0x0311a130, EDI=0x0311a000
EIP=0x6e9954bb, EFLAGS=0x00010246

Top of Stack: (sp=0x032ef160)
0x032ef160:   00000000 0311a130 32d029f0 0311a000
0x032ef170:   02af8f9c 0000101b 6eb89398 032ef198
0x032ef180:   1000593a 0311a130 00000000 0311a000
0x032ef190:   32d029f0 32d029f0 032ef1dc 0098aabd
0x032ef1a0:   03ba76a0 032ef1e4 032ef1f4 00000000
0x032ef1b0:   032ef1ec 00000000 009888c9 032ef1bc
0x032ef1c0:   00000000 032ef1f4 32d03e10 00000000
0x032ef1d0:   32d029f0 00000000 032ef1ec 032ef218 

Instructions: (pc=0x6e9954bb)
0x6e99549b:   f3 ff 83 c4 08 83 7f 04 00 89 7d f0 c7 45 f4 00
0x6e9954ab:   00 00 00 74 08 8d 4d f0 e8 a8 a6 0c 00 8b 45 0c
0x6e9954bb:   8b 08 8b 51 04 8b 42 40 50 56 e8 26 df 07 00 83
0x6e9954cb:   c4 08 83 7d f4 00 89 45 08 74 08 8d 4d f0 e8 c2 


Register to memory mapping:

EAX=0x00000000 is an unknown value
EBX=0x32d029f0 is an oop
{method} 
 - klass: {other class}
ECX=0x0311a000 is a thread
EDX=0x0000101b is an unknown value
ESP=0x032ef160 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0311a000
EBP=0x032ef17c is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0311a000
ESI=0x0311a130 is an unknown value
EDI=0x0311a000 is a thread


Stack: [0x032a0000,0x032f0000],  sp=0x032ef160,  free space=316k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [jvm.dll+0xc54bb]
C  [PvJNI.dll+0x593a]
j  prosilica.Pv.CaptureQueueFrame(Lprosilica/Pv$tHandle;Lprosilica/Pv$tFrame;Lprosilica/Pv$FrameListener;)Lprosilica/Pv$tError;+0
j  lenniemeyn.ZeilenStreamFrameListener.refresh()V+84
j  lenniemeyn.ZeilenStreamFrameListener$1.run()V+4
j  java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch()V+47
j  java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;Ljava/lang/Object;)V+21
j  java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(Ljava/awt/EventQueue;Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;Ljava/lang/Object;)V+3
j  java.awt.EventQueue$3.run()Ljava/lang/Void;+12
j  java.awt.EventQueue$3.run()Ljava/lang/Object;+1
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [jvm.dll+0x14234a]
V  [jvm.dll+0x206ebe]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1423cd]
V  [jvm.dll+0xfc6aa]
C  [java.dll+0x102f]
j  java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+28
j  java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+46
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(I)V+245
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(ILjava/awt/Conditional;Ljava/awt/EventFilter;)V+35
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(ILjava/awt/Conditional;Ljava/awt/Component;)V+11
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(ILjava/awt/Conditional;)V+4
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Ljava/awt/Conditional;)V+3
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run()V+9
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [jvm.dll+0x14234a]
V  [jvm.dll+0x206ebe]
V  [jvm.dll+0x142515]
V  [jvm.dll+0x142577]
V  [jvm.dll+0xed3df]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1636ec]
V  [jvm.dll+0x164147]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1a8d99]
C  [msvcr100.dll+0x5c556]
C  [msvcr100.dll+0x5c600]
C  [kernel32.dll+0xb729]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  prosilica.Pv.CaptureQueueFrame(Lprosilica/Pv$tHandle;Lprosilica/Pv$tFrame;Lprosilica/Pv$FrameListener;)Lprosilica/Pv$tError;+0
j  lenniemeyn.ZeilenStreamFrameListener.refresh()V+84
j  lenniemeyn.ZeilenStreamFrameListener$1.run()V+4
j  java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch()V+47
j  java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;Ljava/lang/Object;)V+21
j  java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(Ljava/awt/EventQueue;Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;Ljava/lang/Object;)V+3
j  java.awt.EventQueue$3.run()Ljava/lang/Void;+12
j  java.awt.EventQueue$3.run()Ljava/lang/Object;+1
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0
j  java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+28
j  java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+46
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(I)V+245
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(ILjava/awt/Conditional;Ljava/awt/EventFilter;)V+35
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(ILjava/awt/Conditional;Ljava/awt/Component;)V+11
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(ILjava/awt/Conditional;)V+4
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Ljava/awt/Conditional;)V+3
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run()V+9
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x0317a000 JavaThread "Thread-21" [_thread_blocked, id=424, stack(0x04130000,0x04180000)]
  0x03178c00 JavaThread "Thread-20" [_thread_blocked, id=2428, stack(0x040e0000,0x04130000)]
  0x03177000 JavaThread "Thread-19" [_thread_blocked, id=3356, stack(0x04090000,0x040e0000)]
  0x03172000 JavaThread "Thread-18" [_thread_blocked, id=2440, stack(0x04040000,0x04090000)]
  0x03170400 JavaThread "Thread-17" [_thread_blocked, id=2504, stack(0x03ff0000,0x04040000)]
  0x0316f000 JavaThread "Thread-16" [_thread_blocked, id=2340, stack(0x03fa0000,0x03ff0000)]
  0x0316d400 JavaThread "Thread-15" [_thread_blocked, id=3444, stack(0x03f50000,0x03fa0000)]
  0x0316bc00 JavaThread "Thread-14" [_thread_blocked, id=3932, stack(0x03f00000,0x03f50000)]
  0x0316a400 JavaThread "Thread-13" [_thread_blocked, id=3360, stack(0x03eb0000,0x03f00000)]
  0x03168c00 JavaThread "Thread-12" [_thread_blocked, id=3976, stack(0x03e60000,0x03eb0000)]
  0x03163800 JavaThread "Thread-11" [_thread_blocked, id=3676, stack(0x03e10000,0x03e60000)]
  0x03162000 JavaThread "Thread-10" [_thread_blocked, id=3108, stack(0x03dc0000,0x03e10000)]
  0x03160800 JavaThread "Thread-9" [_thread_blocked, id=3020, stack(0x03d70000,0x03dc0000)]
  0x0315ec00 JavaThread "Thread-8" [_thread_blocked, id=2564, stack(0x03d20000,0x03d70000)]
  0x0315d400 JavaThread "Thread-7" [_thread_blocked, id=348, stack(0x03cd0000,0x03d20000)]
  0x0315bc00 JavaThread "Thread-6" [_thread_blocked, id=3756, stack(0x03a60000,0x03ab0000)]
  0x0315a800 JavaThread "Thread-5" [_thread_blocked, id=2596, stack(0x03a10000,0x03a60000)]
  0x03159c00 JavaThread "Thread-3" [_thread_blocked, id=1008, stack(0x039c0000,0x03a10000)]
  0x03158c00 JavaThread "Thread-4" [_thread_blocked, id=3940, stack(0x03970000,0x039c0000)]
  0x03149400 JavaThread "TimerQueue" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1816, stack(0x03710000,0x03760000)]
  0x0312b800 JavaThread "D3D Screen Updater" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3916, stack(0x032f0000,0x03340000)]
  0x003ca000 JavaThread "DestroyJavaVM" [_thread_blocked, id=2980, stack(0x00900000,0x00950000)]
=>0x0311a000 JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-0" [_thread_in_vm, id=3208, stack(0x032a0000,0x032f0000)]
  0x02ae0c00 JavaThread "AWT-Windows" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3016, stack(0x02f80000,0x02fd0000)]
  0x02adf400 JavaThread "AWT-Shutdown" [_thread_blocked, id=3556, stack(0x02f30000,0x02f80000)]
  0x02ade400 JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2492, stack(0x02ee0000,0x02f30000)]
  0x02a92800 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2808, stack(0x02e40000,0x02e90000)]
  0x02a8c800 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2356, stack(0x02df0000,0x02e40000)]
  0x02a8ac00 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3944, stack(0x02da0000,0x02df0000)]
  0x02a89800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3752, stack(0x02d50000,0x02da0000)]
  0x02a20c00 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2348, stack(0x02d00000,0x02d50000)]
  0x02a1bc00 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3288, stack(0x02cb0000,0x02d00000)]

Other Threads:
  0x02a1a000 VMThread [stack: 0x02c60000,0x02cb0000] [id=3252]
  0x02a9e000 WatcherThread [stack: 0x02e90000,0x02ee0000] [id=796]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 def new generation   total 5056K, used 166K [0x22c00000, 0x23170000, 0x28150000)
  eden space 4544K,   3% used [0x22c00000, 0x22c29b48, 0x23070000)
  from space 512K,   0% used [0x23070000, 0x23070000, 0x230f0000)
  to   space 512K,   0% used [0x230f0000, 0x230f0000, 0x23170000)
 tenured generation   total 10944K, used 3020K [0x28150000, 0x28c00000, 0x32c00000)
   the space 10944K,  27% used [0x28150000, 0x28443098, 0x28443200, 0x28c00000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 1153K [0x32c00000, 0x33800000, 0x36c00000)
   the space 12288K,   9% used [0x32c00000, 0x32d20638, 0x32d20800, 0x33800000)
    ro space 10240K,  44% used [0x36c00000, 0x3707c1d8, 0x3707c200, 0x37600000)
    rw space 12288K,  52% used [0x37600000, 0x37c440c0, 0x37c44200, 0x38200000)

Card table byte_map: [0x02b00000,0x02bb0000] byte_map_base: 0x029ea000

Polling page: 0x00950000

Code Cache  [0x00980000, 0x00a50000, 0x02980000)
 total_blobs=385 nmethods=167 adapters=155 free_code_cache=31949Kb largest_free_block=32716224

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 4.896 Thread 0x02a8c800  163             java.lang.String::indexOf (7 bytes)
Event: 4.896 Thread 0x02a8c800 nmethod 163 0x00a4b688 code [0x00a4b780, 0x00a4b81c]
Event: 5.213 Thread 0x02a8c800  164             java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$Sync::nonfairTryAcquire (67 bytes)
Event: 5.214 Thread 0x02a8c800 nmethod 164 0x00a4b888 code [0x00a4b990, 0x00a4bb0c]
Event: 5.214 Thread 0x02a8c800  165   !         sun.awt.SunToolkit::flushPendingEvents (73 bytes)
Event: 5.214 Thread 0x02a8c800 nmethod 165 0x00a4bb88 code [0x00a4bce0, 0x00a4becc]
Event: 5.214 Thread 0x02a8c800  166   !         sun.awt.PostEventQueue::flush (84 bytes)
Event: 5.214 Thread 0x02a8c800 nmethod 166 0x00a4c208 code [0x00a4c320, 0x00a4c608]
Event: 5.379 Thread 0x02a8c800  167             java.awt.EventQueue::eventToCacheIndex (69 bytes)
Event: 5.379 Thread 0x02a8c800 nmethod 167 0x00a4c7c8 code [0x00a4c8c0, 0x00a4c9e0]

GC Heap History (4 events):
Event: 4.006 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=0 (full 0):
 def new generation   total 4928K, used 2696K [0x22c00000, 0x23150000, 0x28150000)
  eden space 4416K,  61% used [0x22c00000, 0x22ea2120, 0x23050000)
  from space 512K,   0% used [0x23050000, 0x23050000, 0x230d0000)
  to   space 512K,   0% used [0x230d0000, 0x230d0000, 0x23150000)
 tenured generation   total 10944K, used 0K [0x28150000, 0x28c00000, 0x32c00000)
   the space 10944K,   0% used [0x28150000, 0x28150000, 0x28150200, 0x28c00000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 1116K [0x32c00000, 0x33800000, 0x36c00000)
   the space 12288K,   9% used [0x32c00000, 0x32d17218, 0x32d17400, 0x33800000)
    ro space 10240K,  44% used [0x36c00000, 0x3707c1d8, 0x3707c200, 0x37600000)
    rw space 12288K,  52% used [0x37600000, 0x37c440c0, 0x37c44200, 0x38200000)
Event: 4.013 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=1 (full 0):
 def new generation   total 4928K, used 512K [0x22c00000, 0x23150000, 0x28150000)
  eden space 4416K,   0% used [0x22c00000, 0x22c00000, 0x23050000)
  from space 512K, 100% used [0x230d0000, 0x23150000, 0x23150000)
  to   space 512K,   0% used [0x23050000, 0x23050000, 0x230d0000)
 tenured generation   total 10944K, used 292K [0x28150000, 0x28c00000, 0x32c00000)
   the space 10944K,   2% used [0x28150000, 0x28199120, 0x28199200, 0x28c00000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 1116K [0x32c00000, 0x33800000, 0x36c00000)
   the space 12288K,   9% used [0x32c00000, 0x32d17218, 0x32d17400, 0x33800000)
    ro space 10240K,  44% used [0x36c00000, 0x3707c1d8, 0x3707c200, 0x37600000)
    rw space 12288K,  52% used [0x37600000, 0x37c440c0, 0x37c44200, 0x38200000)
}
Event: 5.439 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=1 (full 0):
 def new generation   total 4928K, used 4928K [0x22c00000, 0x23150000, 0x28150000)
  eden space 4416K, 100% used [0x22c00000, 0x23050000, 0x23050000)
  from space 512K, 100% used [0x230d0000, 0x23150000, 0x23150000)
  to   space 512K,   0% used [0x23050000, 0x23050000, 0x230d0000)
 tenured generation   total 10944K, used 8996K [0x28150000, 0x28c00000, 0x32c00000)
   the space 10944K,  82% used [0x28150000, 0x28a19130, 0x28a19200, 0x28c00000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 1153K [0x32c00000, 0x33800000, 0x36c00000)
   the space 12288K,   9% used [0x32c00000, 0x32d20638, 0x32d20800, 0x33800000)
    ro space 10240K,  44% used [0x36c00000, 0x3707c1d8, 0x3707c200, 0x37600000)
    rw space 12288K,  52% used [0x37600000, 0x37c440c0, 0x37c44200, 0x38200000)
Event: 5.463 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=2 (full 1):
 def new generation   total 5056K, used 0K [0x22c00000, 0x23170000, 0x28150000)
  eden space 4544K,   0% used [0x22c00000, 0x22c00000, 0x23070000)
  from space 512K,   0% used [0x23070000, 0x23070000, 0x230f0000)
  to   space 512K,   0% used [0x230f0000, 0x230f0000, 0x23170000)
 tenured generation   total 10944K, used 3020K [0x28150000, 0x28c00000, 0x32c00000)
   the space 10944K,  27% used [0x28150000, 0x28443098, 0x28443200, 0x28c00000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 1153K [0x32c00000, 0x33800000, 0x36c00000)
   the space 12288K,   9% used [0x32c00000, 0x32d20638, 0x32d20800, 0x33800000)
    ro space 10240K,  44% used [0x36c00000, 0x3707c1d8, 0x3707c200, 0x37600000)
    rw space 12288K,  52% used [0x37600000, 0x37c440c0, 0x37c44200, 0x38200000)
}

Deoptimization events (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 4.026 Thread 0x030fc800 Threw 0x22e6baa0 at C:\re\jdk7u79\2331\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1304
Event: 4.027 Thread 0x030fc800 Threw 0x22e6e2e8 at C:\re\jdk7u79\2331\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1304
Event: 4.028 Thread 0x030fc800 Threw 0x22e73698 at C:\re\jdk7u79\2331\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1304
Event: 4.573 Thread 0x030fc800 Threw 0x22e9aa30 at C:\re\jdk7u79\2331\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1304
Event: 4.580 Thread 0x030fc800 Threw 0x22e9e420 at C:\re\jdk7u79\2331\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1304
Event: 4.581 Thread 0x030fc800 Threw 0x22ea21a8 at C:\re\jdk7u79\2331\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1304
Event: 4.582 Thread 0x030fc800 Threw 0x22ea41d8 at C:\re\jdk7u79\2331\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1304
Event: 4.594 Thread 0x030fc800 Threw 0x22ea6f70 at C:\re\jdk7u79\2331\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1304
Event: 4.595 Thread 0x030fc800 Threw 0x22ea9510 at C:\re\jdk7u79\2331\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1304
Event: 5.465 Thread 0x0311a000 Threw 0x22c0fa68 at C:\re\jdk7u79\2331\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp:4123

Events (10 events):
Event: 5.464 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias done
Event: 5.464 Thread 0x02aa0c00 Thread exited: 0x02aa0c00
Event: 5.464 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias
Event: 5.464 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias done
Event: 5.464 Thread 0x02aa0c00 Thread added: 0x02aa0c00
Event: 5.464 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias
Event: 5.464 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias done
Event: 5.464 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias
Event: 5.464 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias done
Event: 5.464 Thread 0x02aa0c00 Thread exited: 0x02aa0c00


Dynamic libraries:
0x00400000 - 0x0042f000     C:\Programme\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe
0x7c910000 - 0x7c9c9000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll
0x7c800000 - 0x7c908000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\kernel32.dll
0x77da0000 - 0x77e4a000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x77e50000 - 0x77ee3000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x77fc0000 - 0x77fd1000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\Secur32.dll
0x7e360000 - 0x7e3f1000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\USER32.dll
0x77ef0000 - 0x77f39000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\GDI32.dll
0x773a0000 - 0x774a3000     C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.2600.6028_x-ww_61e65202\COMCTL32.dll
0x77be0000 - 0x77c38000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x77f40000 - 0x77fb6000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x76330000 - 0x7634d000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x78aa0000 - 0x78b5f000     C:\Programme\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre\bin\msvcr100.dll
0x6e8d0000 - 0x6ec59000     C:\Programme\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll
0x71a30000 - 0x71a3a000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WSOCK32.dll
0x71a10000 - 0x71a27000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x71a00000 - 0x71a08000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WS2HELP.dll
0x76af0000 - 0x76b1e000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WINMM.dll
0x76bb0000 - 0x76bbb000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x6e820000 - 0x6e82c000     C:\Programme\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre\bin\verify.dll
0x6d590000 - 0x6d5b0000     C:\Programme\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre\bin\java.dll
0x6e8b0000 - 0x6e8c3000     C:\Programme\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre\bin\zip.dll
0x6d110000 - 0x6d253000     C:\Programme\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre\bin\awt.dll
0x770f0000 - 0x7717b000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
0x774b0000 - 0x775ee000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ole32.dll
0x5b0f0000 - 0x5b128000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\uxtheme.dll
0x746a0000 - 0x746ec000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\MSCTF.dll
0x75250000 - 0x7527e000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\msctfime.ime
0x4fd50000 - 0x4fef6000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\d3d9.dll
0x6de80000 - 0x6de86000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\d3d8thk.dll
0x77bd0000 - 0x77bd8000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\VERSION.dll
0x7e670000 - 0x7ee91000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\SHELL32.dll
0x6d380000 - 0x6d3b9000     C:\Programme\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre\bin\fontmanager.dll
0x6e5f0000 - 0x6e604000     C:\Programme\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre\bin\net.dll
0x6e610000 - 0x6e61f000     C:\Programme\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre\bin\nio.dll
0x6e7d0000 - 0x6e800000     C:\Programme\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre\bin\t2k.dll
0x10000000 - 0x1001f000     C:\Programme\Allied Vision Technologies\GigESDK\bin-pc\PvJNI.dll
0x03490000 - 0x035a8000     C:\Programme\Allied Vision Technologies\GigESDK\bin-pc\PvAPI.dll
0x76d20000 - 0x76d39000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\iphlpapi.dll
0x719b0000 - 0x719f0000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\mswsock.dll
0x66710000 - 0x66769000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\hnetcfg.dll
0x719f0000 - 0x719f8000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\wshtcpip.dll
0x59dd0000 - 0x59e71000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\dbghelp.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
java_command: lenniemeyn.MakoG_Swing
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=C:\Programme\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin
PATH=C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\All Users\Anwendungsdaten\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\sybase\DataAccess\ADONET\dll;C:\sybase\DataAccess\OLEDB\dll;C:\sybase\DataAccess\ODBC\dll;C:\sybase\OCS-15_0\lib3p;C:\sybase\OCS-15_0\dll;C:\sybase\OCS-15_0\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_2\bin;C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Programme\CA\DCS\CAWIN\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Programme\CA\DSM\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\CA\SC\CAM\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\sybase\DBISQL\bin;C:\SmartView;C:\Programme\CA\SC\Csam\SockAdapter\bin;C:\Programme\CA\SC\CBB\;C:\Programme\STEMMER IMAGING\Common Vision Blox\;C:\Programme\Intel\DMIX;C:\Programme\Allied Vision Technologies\GigESDK\bin-pc
USERNAME=Student_OIS
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=x86 Family 6 Model 15 Stepping 11, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows XP Build 2600 Service Pack 3

CPU:total 2 (2 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 15 stepping 11, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, tsc

Memory: 4k page, physical 2095460k(1193932k free), swap 3511152k(2755736k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (24.79-b02) for windows-x86 JRE (1.7.0_79-b15), built on Apr 10 2015 16:49:13 by "java_re" with unknown MS VC++:1600

time: Thu Mar 17 14:18:27 2016
elapsed time: 5 seconds
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried with the latest version of the camera's API? 
Link to the SDK (http://www.1stvision.com/AVT-gige-camera-software-downloads.html)

Here you can find documentation about SDK : https://www.alliedvision.com/fileadmin/content/documents/products/software/software/PvAPI/docu/PvAPI_SDK_Manual.pdf

I hope it can help.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I downloaded the latest Version of the API directly from the producer. I got version 1.28 PvAPI_SDK.

So you think it's definetly an error caused by the SDK, respectively an Error caused by using the native libraries?

Comment: Yes, a similar case I've found here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/tsg/TSG-VM/html/crashes.html in the section: 4.1.2 Crash in Native Code

In this case the file is "C  [PvJNI.dll+0x593a]" which is part of PvAPI SDK.

Comment: Much thanks for this link! I will try to resolve the Problem with the help of this site.